# Finding similar numbers in a list and getting the average

Tags: python

[image]

I currently have the numbers above in a list. How would you go about adding similar numbers (by nearest 850) and finding average to make the list smaller.

For example I have the list

```
l = [2000,2200,5000,2350]
```

In this list, i want to find numbers that are similar by n+500

So I want all the numbers similar by n+500 which are 2000,2200,2350 to be added and divided by the amount there which is 3 to find the mean. This will then replace the three numbers added. so the list will now be `l = [2183,5000]`

As the image above shows the numbers in the list. Here I would like the numbers close by n+850 to all be selected and the mean to be found

Comment: Please post the numbers as text, rather than [using an image](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors-when-asking-a-question).

Comment: `n+500` to *what*?  A single value, each value … ? If it’s each value, the list will not get smaller.  Please clarify.  There has to be a breaking point.  Given the distribution of values in the list, virtually all will be +500 to something in the list.

Comment: to a single value

Comment: A post was deleted because it was downvoted. Can this please be explained on the reasoning for this?

Comment: It seems that you look for some kind of clustering algorithm (something like K-means), but it's not clear how many clusters are expected

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that you look for a clustering algorithm - something like K-means.

This algorithm is implemented in [scikit-learn package](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.cluster.KMeans.html)

After you find your K means, you can count how many of your data were clustered with that mean, and make your computations.

However, it's not clear in your case what is K. You can try and run the algorithm for several K values until you get your constraints (the `n+500` distance between the means)

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
import numpy as np
l = np.array([2000,2200,5000,2350])

# find similar numbers (that are within each 500 fold)
similar = l // 500

# for each similar group get the average and convert it to integer (as in the desired output)
new_list = [np.average(l[similar == num]).astype(int) for num in np.unique(similar)]

print(new_list)
```

Output:

```
[2183, 5000]
```

Answer (score 0):

Step 1:

```
list = [5620.77978515625,
 7388.43017578125,
 7683.580078125,
 8296.6513671875,
 8320.82421875,
 8557.51953125,
 8743.5,
 9163.220703125,
 9804.7939453125,
 9913.86328125,
 9940.1396484375,
 9951.74609375,
 10074.23828125,
 10947.0419921875,
 11048.662109375,
 11704.099609375,
 11958.5,
 11964.8232421875,
 12335.70703125,
 13103.0,
 13129.529296875,
 16463.177734375,
 16930.900390625,
 17712.400390625,
 18353.400390625,
 19390.96484375,
 20089.0,
 34592.15625,
 36542.109375,
 39478.953125,
 40782.078125,
 41295.26953125,
 42541.6796875,
 42893.58203125,
 44578.27734375,
 45077.578125,
 48022.2890625,
 52535.13671875,
 58330.5703125,
 61597.91796875,
 62757.12890625,
 64242.79296875,
 64863.09765625,
 66930.390625]
```

Step 2:

```
seen = [] #to log used indices pairs
diff_dic = {} #to record indices and diff
for i,a in enumerate(list):
  for j,b in enumerate(list):
    if i!=j and (i,j)[::-1] not in seen:
      seen.append((i,j))
      diff_dic[(i,j)] = abs(a-b)
      

keys = []
for ind, diff in diff_dic.items():
  if diff <= 850:
    keys.append(ind)
uniques_k = [] #to record unique indices
for pair in keys:
  for key in pair:
    if key not in uniques_k:
      uniques_k.append(key)

import numpy as np
list_arr = np.array(list)
nearest_avg = np.mean(list_arr[uniques_k])
list_arr = np.delete(list_arr, uniques_k)
list_arr = np.append(list_arr, nearest_avg)
list_arr
```

output:

```
array([ 5620.77978516, 34592.15625, 36542.109375, 39478.953125, 48022.2890625, 52535.13671875, 58330.5703125 , 61597.91796875, 62757.12890625, 66930.390625  , 20566.00205365])
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

You just need a conditional list comprehension like this:

```
l = [2000,2200,5000,2350]
n = 2000    
a = [ (x) for x in l if ((n -250) < x < (n + 250)) ]
```

Then you can average with

```
np.mean(a)
```

or whatever method you prefer.

Comment: Not quite.  The `x < n+500` comparison will allow *all* values of `x` which are less than `n+500`, including zero.  Rather than values which are *close* to `n`, with a tolerance of +500.  Additionally; `n` is not static.

Comment: You are right, I just wanted to give the idea because it's not clear exactly what is wanted, but it would have been more precise to directly specify a range. I will change that. Ha, ok, it is clear because there is an accepted answer and I did not correctly interpret the question.